# simplification of square root of $\pi$

Tags: derivatives, radicals

Using the power rule, my textbook differentiates this:

$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x^{2+\pi}})$

like this, using the power rule:

$$\begin{align}
=& \frac{d}{dx}(x^{1+(\pi/2)}) \tag{1}\\
=& (1+\frac{\pi}2)x^{1+(\pi/2)-1} \tag{2}\\
=& \frac12(2+\pi)\sqrt{x^{\pi}} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

I understand how we went from (1) to (2), but I don't understand how $x^{2+\pi}$ became $(x^{1+(\pi/2)}$ in 1, since the square root of $\pi \neq \pi/2$.

I'm also lost with regards to the steps between $2$ and $3$.

Comment: First: $\sqrt{x^a} = (x^a)^{1/2} = x^{a/2}$. Second: they subtracted the 1 in the exponent, and undid a change similar to that at the beginning. Remember that $\sqrt{x^a} \neq x^{\sqrt a}$ (which I think is what you are trying)

Comment: $\sqrt{x^{2+\pi}}=\sqrt{x^{2(1+\frac{\pi}{2})}}=\big|x^{1+\frac{\pi}{2}}\big|$.

Comment: TokenToucan, Ok yes you were right, that was what I was trying. If you put your comment in an answer I'll check it as correct. Re. 3, I take it to mean they just undid $x^{\pi/2}$ and turned it back into $\sqrt{x^{\pi}}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{x^{2+\pi}}=x^{\frac{2+\pi}2}=x^{1+\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

No its $x^{(2+\pi).0.5}=x^{1+(\pi/2)}$